# Where is the definition of drag_select?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3.
I'm trying to make a plugin for high accuracy word separator for Japanese.

I know that I can separate words with "word_separators" in "Preferences.sublime-settings," but it's not sufficient for Japanese.

I saw "Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap" and find that "drag_select" function does word separating, so I want to see the definition of "drag_select."
However, I can't find the definition in anywhere.

Where can I see the definition?

Comment: I believe that `drag_select` is in the core, so it's not exposed directly as something that you can manipulate, just call. You can however catch when it's doing something with `EventListener.on_text_command` and use that to make it execute a different command of your own invention to get it to do what you want.

Comment: That's too bad...
I wanted to see how to separate words, how to detect mouse up event, and how to recognize a track of mouse moving.
I couldn't see such things, so finally I made those function.
https://github.com/ASHIJANKEN/JapaneseWordSeparator
Sorry for Japanese README, but comments in sourcecodes are English.